# ASP.NET, Multiple Val Summary not working; required field val not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with editable rows on the aspx page. The row has a textbox and a required field validator associated to it. On 'save' button click on that row, the required field valiator fires, It is tied to a validationsummary at the top of the page.

Now I have this panel below the repeater with a text box and a save button. This panel is 'opened' using the jquery show method on the click on a linkbutton at the top of this panel.
The required field validator is not firing for this texbox. I have a different validation summary for this textbox; as I need to trigger the validations on click on its save button only.

So I have the code like this,

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummary" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" />

 <asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummary1" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2" EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" />

<asp:Repeater ID="Teams" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbTeamNameHeader" runat="server" Text="TeamNameHeader"></asp:Label></th>

<th></th> </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTeamName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "txtTeamName")%>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdFieldValTeamName" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be blank" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtTeamName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regularExprTeamName" ErrorMessage="Invalid input for the team name" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtTeamName" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>

            <td>
                 <asp:Panel ID="panelSave" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonSave" runat="server" CommandName="Save" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Text="SAVE" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="CANCEL" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonAddTeam" runat="server" Text="Add New Team" />
<div id="AddPanelDiv" style="display:none;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddTeam" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdFieldValAddTeam" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be blank" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtAddTeam"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regularExprValAddTeam" ErrorMessage="Invalid format" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtAddTeam" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonCancel" runat="server" Text="CANCEL"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonSaveNewTeam" runat="server" OnClick="linkbuttonSaveNewTeam_OnClick" Text="SAVE" CausesValidation="true" />
    </div>
```

Why on earth the validators for the bottom panel fire? On click of that save button, it straightaway goes to the page method onclick.

If I remove the validation group and click on the save in the repeater, it fires! But thats not what I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2"` on your second button it looks like.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbuttonSaveNewTeam" runat="server" OnClick="linkbuttonSaveNewTeam_OnClick"
     Text="SAVE" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2" />
```

Comment: my bad..let me try this.. thanks a lot for the reply!